# React Select as children of a popover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Hello I've run into an issue while using react-select.

In my current project I had to use react-select into a form, which is inside a popover, at which is visible by clicking
a button.

The issue that we are facing with the component is when a value is selected, the menu is removed from the DOM before we
check if the given element is inside, doing so it fails the test and closes the popover.

Below is a working poc of the issue. When we are clicking the input, opening the native select, or selecting a value
using native, it registers as inside, sadly the same behaviour doesn't apply to react-select as when a value is selected
the menu closes (it's being removed from the DOM).

Note: one requirement is to keep the accessibility implemented in react-select (like toggling menu on space key, etc.)

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Select from 'react-select';

const PlainPopover = ({visible, children, onOutsideClick}) => {
    const [ref, setRef] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const click = e => {
            const event = e;
            if (!ref) return;
            if (!ref.contains(event.target)) {
                console.log("Outside click", ref, event.target)
                onOutsideClick(event);
            }
            console.log("Inside click")
        }
        document.addEventListener("click", click)
        return () => document.removeEventListener("click", click)
    }, [visible, ref])

    return <div ref={setRef} id={"#popover"} style={{backgroundColor: "#bababa"}}>
        {children}
    </div>
}

const App = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState();
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
    return <>
        <button onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>Open</button>
        {visible && <PlainPopover visible={visible} onOutsideClick={() => setVisible(false)}>
            <form style={{display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", maxWidth: 200}}>
                <div>This is inside</div>
                <Select options={["1", "2"].map(e => ({value: e, label: e}))}
                        onChange={setValue}
                        value={value}/>
                <input/>
                <select>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                </select>
                <div>As well as this</div>
            </form>
        </PlainPopover>
        }
    </>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I've tried 2 solutions:

- overwriting the `Menu`, `MenuPortal` `MenuList` components to allways render the menu, but hiding it in css, the issue being that the visibilty isn't controlled by them.
- overwriting the `Control` component and giving its props `{..parentProps, menuIsVisible: true}` but that doesn't force
  the menu to be always visible

Any ideas to make it work?

Tried solutions from comments :

@Adriano Repetti : Wild guess: do not check if your ref contains the target. Do the opposite: FROM THE TARGET keep walking up the tree (parent -> parent -> ...) until you find your container or there is nothing left to check.

Using this recursive function:

```
const isElementParent = (element, parent) => {
    console.log(element.parentNode)
    while (element.parentNode) {
        console.log(element);
        if (element === parent) {
            return true;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}
```

changed if condition from `if (!ref.contains(event.target))` to `!isElementParent(event.target, ref)`

Comment: Wild guess: do not check if your ref contains the target. Do the opposite: FROM THE TARGET keep walking up the tree (parent -> parent -> ...) until you find your container or there is nothing left to check. And, BTW, this is just one of the many cases you'll need to handle to have an effective popover (that's why there are so many libraries out there - some pretty good)

Comment: Also, you should render the popover inside a React portal, you probably do not want it (or its children) truncated by the viewport of its container. Note that also a control (used inside your popover) could render himself this way (virtual DOM !== DOM) then to find if a click is "inside" or "outside" is WAY more complicate this this (you MIGHT use an overlay, for example).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks for the suggestion!. Regarding your second reply the reason that I the popover implementation is so minimalist is to show that even a plain example wouldn't work.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti now regarding the first, now I've tried using this simple function `const isElementParent = (element, parent) => {
    console.log(element.parentNode)
    while (element.parentNode) {
        console.log(element);
        if (element === parent) {
            return true;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
}`  and having it be tested like so `if (!isElementParent(event.target, ref))` rather than `!ref.contains(event.target)` but still no luck.

Comment: Interestingly the parent logs for events inside react-select doesn't "bubble" up to html, it stops at the MenuList `<div class=" css-4ljt47-MenuList">`

Comment: It could be the event handler there calls `stopPropagation()` but then why your function is called? (BTW that's why of the reasons you might consider using an overlay instead of listining for click on `document`)